# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500 when building a chat application

Tags: python, django-channels

I am trying to build a chat application using Django-channels. I am facing the above issue when running the websocket connection:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
```

```sh
(index):14 WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/chat/yellamma/' failed:
Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500 (anonymous) @ (index):14 
(index):23 Chat socket closed unexpectedly chatSocket.onclose @ (index):23
```

[image: Error shown in this image].

Comment: And your django-channels code?

Answer (score 1):

You might have not install redis in your os.

https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/releases/download/win-3.0.504/Redis-x64-3.0.504.msi

Download redis first with this link and try again.
I have tried it and successfully made it.

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Zohaib, You saved my lot of time.